# Tensorflow placeholder error

Tags: python, audio, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have been playing around with tensorflow, I have managed to train the mode and serve it but when i try run the client to send data for classification i get this error

> grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError:
>   AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details="You must feed
>   a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float
>   [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder_output_shapes=[[]],
>   dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]")

I do not quite understand this error, here are my placeholders

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,n_dim])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,n_classes])
```

And i used the builder as in the documentation, writing the prediction_signature as well as classification signatures.

If any may know why this is happening i would be extremely grateful

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually set your values to something. A placeholder is simply a placeholder and must be set to an actual value using a feed_dict.

Something like this, note the sess.run line:

```
import tensorflow as tf

X_vals = 1
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

sess = tf.Session()

# sess.run(X) # This will throw the error you see
sess.run(X, feed_dict={X: X_vals}) # This works
```

Comment: Hey SuperTetelman, I have feed data to it,`_,cost = sess.run([train_step,cross_entropy],feed_dict={x:training_features,y:training_labels})`  the error comes when i try post from the client, how would i make sure the place holder is feed with the data?

Comment: Is the code you just posted the actual code? If so you are using X as your placeholder and x as your input, which could cause problems.

Comment: hey SuperTetelman I have used lower case x for my placeholder that i have used as my input, but the error was in my y placeholder and how it was referenced later in the code and managed to fix that and it works now.